# Iterate Over Ext JS Form Components of Particular Type

Tags: javascript, extjs, combobox

I have an `Ext.form.Panel` which contains a mixture of "typical" fields: `textfield`, `combobox`, `checkboxfield`, and the like. Each `combobox` has `forceselection : true` and - therefore - an associated store. My goal is to loop over each of the fields in the `Panel`, determine whether it is a `combobox`, then do "some stuff" - i.e. load the associated store.

Two questions (each holding the hand of the over):

1. Is it possible to `Ext.each` over a particular "type" of component on a panel? Or, to approach the problem slightly differently: is it possible to select a group of components matching a particular type?
2. If not, how do I determine the type of the component at run-time?

Currently, I am using a list of identifiers, [iterating](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0/5.0.0-apidocs/#!/api/Ext-method-each) over each identifier, and running a query against the panel, e.g.

```
var comboBoxIds : [
    'dogs',
    'cats',
    'fish'
];

Ext.each(comboBoxIds, function(comboId) {
    var comboBox = panel.queryById(comboId);

    //....

});
```

The above being a very simplistic reduction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `query` method to get what you need, and then iterate over the array:

```
var combos = panel.query('combobox[forceSelection=true]');

for (var i = 0; i < combos.length; i++) {
    var combo = combos[i];
    ...
}
```

More on the ComponentQuery syntax: http://docs-origin.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/5.1.0-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.ComponentQuery